# Test append with gtest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

How to test a try-catch block with gtest (gmock available for the matter) if I can't provoke `std:string exceptions` ?

```
int
Test::function_to_be_tested( std::string& url ) const
{  
    try
    {
        url.append( "?" );

    }
    catch( std::exception const& e ) {
        logger.log(LOG_ERROR, e.what());
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

I come from a Java world, and in Java I would mock `String` with some mocking framework, and `spy` on `append` to attach a function of my own which always will throw an exception. Is this possible in C++ (98) ?

Answer (score 1):

Mocking `String` would be tricky even in Java. In C++, forget it.

Instead, create a string that is already `max_size()` characters long. The `append()` should throw then.

Comment: Well, I have tried to create it, but the test program exits because of `std::bad_alloc` . I can't create such a big string even in the test program.